# Stacktrace with SQL injection?

Tags: java, oracle, sql-injection, stack-trace

If i insert a quote symbol " in the `codContract` parameter I receive the following error.

> Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-00972: identifier too long
>
> The error may exist in mappers/existence.xml The error may involve
>   com.iv.queryinterface.AssistenzaMapper.getTitlesFromCodContratct-Inline
>   The error occurred while setting parameters

SQL:

```
SELECT t.id_title,
       c.des_lastname,
       c.des_firstname,
       to_char(t.dta_raw, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DTA_RAW,
       DECODE(t.cod_statustitle, '1', 'Raw', '2', 'Stated') AS STATUS_TITLE
FROM Ivf_Policy p,
     Ivf_Title t,
     Ivg_Client c,
     Ivf_Price pr
WHERE Cod_Contract = TEST
      AND p.id_policy = t.id_policy
      AND t.cod_type_title IN(2, 3, 13)
AND t.cod_statustitle IN(1, 2)
AND t.cod_client = c.cod_client
AND t.id_price = pr.id_price;
```

> Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier too
>   long

In this example, i set " TEST as value for the codContract parameter. My questions are:

Is this an exploitable SQL injection or a false positive that just prints an sql error into the stack trace?

Comment: How are you setting the value of `Cod_Contract` ?

Comment: Please edit and add your `INSERT` statement

Comment: @Berger There is an input that require a numeric value. But if i insert " TEST it generate a stack-trace error containing this. It's exploitable as sql injection or it's just an error message?

Comment: I didn't develop this, i've just been asked to secure it. If i try with the @ symbol for example i receive this error

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

The stack-trace error is inside of this script

<script id="errors" type="text/x-kendo-template">

Answer (score 0):

The code is susceptible to SQL injection, and does no escaping. All that is avoidable by the use of PreparedStatement. Where the query string is not composed dynamically.

Now `"TEST` is the first part of an SQL identifier till a closing double quote.
I do not want to instruct readers on hacking, but think what something like

```
"'' OR 1=1 "
+ "UNION SELECT u.login, u.password, '', '', '', '' "
+ "FROM users"
+ "\u0000-- ";
```

might reveal on data.

Comment: What if your code is printed as text in the reply?

I saw that the error is inside of a script tag

**<script id="errors" type="text/x-kendo-template">**

I think it may be a false positive.

Comment: One can easily intercept the communications (TamperData). One can read the source text; several hackers, at least on the agencies' side, also use javascript engines with which to retrieve all data.

Comment: I think that in this case it's not possible to exploit the sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.sql.PreparedStatement` for avoiding SQL injection.

```
String query =
        "SELECT " +
                "        t.id_title                                 , " +
                "        c.des_lastname                             , " +
                "        c.des_firstname                            , " +
                "        TO_CHAR(t.dta_raw, 'DD/MM/YYYY')                     AS DTA_RAW, " +
                "        DECODE(t.cod_statustitle, '1', 'Raw', '2', 'Stated') AS STATUS_TITLE " +
                "FROM " +
                "        Ivf_Policy p, " +
                "        Ivf_Title  t, " +
                "        Ivg_Client c, " +
                "        Ivf_Price  pr " +
                "WHERE " +
                "1 = 1 AND " +
                "        Cod_Contract = ? " +
                "AND     p.id_policy  = t.id_policy " +
                "AND     t.cod_type_title IN(2, " +
                "                            3, " +
                "                            13) " +
                "AND     t.cod_statustitle IN(1, " +
                "                             2) " +
                "AND     t.cod_client = c.cod_client " +
                "AND     t.id_price   = pr.id_price;";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, 'TEST');
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid SQL injection, do not append parameter values directly to SQL queries.
Use bind variables instead.

Thanks.